# Robot localization: Odom tf is far offset from Map tf

Tags: ros, ros2, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Recently, I am using the robot-localization package to fuse all my sensors and does the localization for my robot.
And as I was testing the localization result outdoors, I found something strange in rviz2.

In this test, I made the robot move in a rectangular shape.
In rviz2: The ***red*** arrow represents odometry topic on /odom/local; the ***green*** arrow represents odometry topic on /odom/global

At first, the **Odom tf** and the **Map tf is close** to each other, as shown in picture 1.

However, during the rectangular movement, the Odom tf began to **move away** from the Map tf, as show in picture 2,3

In the end, I moved the robot back to where it started. Although both /odom/local and /odom/global (the red and green arrow) **indicate that the robot is back to where it began** (the origin in the map frame). But the Map tf and the Odom tf are **far apart from each other.**

Thus, I wonder if this is something expected?
And if that is expected, does this mean that I have my robot-localization configured properly? In the end, both **/odom/local** and **/odom/global** indicate that my robot is **only about 0.5 meters** away from where it begins, which is acceptable to my requirement.

### image 1

[image: image description]

### image 2

[image: image description]

### image 3

[image: image description]

### image 4

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417498/robot-localization:-odom-tf-is-far-offset-from-map-tf/) by [sdu568](https://answers.ros.org/users/103946/sdu568/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2023-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this is expected. As the odometry of your robot drifts (see this answer for more details: https://answers.ros.org/question/188882/why-can-the-odom-frame-drift/?answer=188887#post-id-188887) the robot-localization package starts to compensate for the drift and therefore "map" and "odom" frames will diverge.

If the final position error is acceptable for your application, then I would say your robot localization is configured properly, although there is always room for improvement.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2023-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdu568](https://answers.ros.org/users/103946/sdu568/) on 2023-07-19**:
Thanks for the clear explanation!